# html pre wont change my new lines

Tags: html, angularjs

Im using mongodb to store some details. in this case, a testmess string.

```
                    testmess = "Angrep:  /n beskyttelse: /n Intelligens";
```

and saving that do db.
im also retrieving it with `<pre>{{ testmess }}</pre>`

but what i get is:

```
Angrep:  /n beskyttelse: /n Intelligens
```

why wont the `<pre>`work with it?  same applies to `<br>`

Comment: explain the issue better with some real time results and the new line character is \n not /n

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly working as expected:

> [Whitespace inside this element [pre] is displayed as typed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

So it prints out what it get and does not interprets anything inside `testmess`.

To have a line break on your site, you have to have it in your `testmess`:

```
testmess = "Angrep:  
            beskyttelse:
            Intelligens";
```

Comment: How can i Get IT to make New lines with IT ?